# React Native: How to trigger function when app comes back to foreground, in app that DOES NOT use function components?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm adding updates to a React Native app that uses class components, and want to have a function triggered every time the user opens the app. For example, if they minimize and then reopen it. I know you can use `AppState` if the app uses function components, but is there any way to achieve this with class components?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can listen for an app state change with class components:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { AppState, StyleSheet, Text, View } from "react-native";

class AppStateExample extends Component {
  state = {
    appState: AppState.currentState
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    AppState.addEventListener("change", this._handleAppStateChange);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    AppState.removeEventListener("change", this._handleAppStateChange);
  }

  _handleAppStateChange = nextAppState => {
    if (
      this.state.appState.match(/inactive|background/) &&
      nextAppState === "active"
    ) {
      console.log("App has come to the foreground!");
    }
    this.setState({ appState: nextAppState });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>Current state is: {this.state.appState}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Source: https://reactnative.dev/docs/appstate (click on `Class Component`) above the code sample to switch from the default `Function Component` code.

Comment: This worked, I had just missed the fact that they had the class component code too. Thanks!